# Adding content directly after a floated image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, psd

Hello I'm trying to code a template (my first), (without using bootstrap, to improve my css skills), which I found online, and I'm having an issue in the portfolio area, which I called "gallery" in my code.

The result in this area, that I'm after is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UgSD.png

And what I'm getting is:
https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/BReraN

I thought this was a clearfix problem, but the `<section>` is cleared. How should I solve this issue?

Secondly, the images in the template are imported using the `<img>` element, so that's why I decided to do the same, but wouldn't importing them as a background-image, the better and more correct approach ?

Also, are there any good tutorials, or any other ways to improve coding PSD templates ? Because, even though, I have watched a billion "CSS basics" videos, I'm really struggling with coding PSD designs, don't know the best practices, and haven't been able to find any good videos for that, that are in english and with no usage of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each block could look like this, move your text into the img block, and wrap it with another sub div block with class `img-text`:

```
  <div class="projects">
    <div class="gallery-image">
      <a href="">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
      <div class="img-text">
        <h4>A project</h4>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

then add following css:

```
.gallery-image a {
  background: white;
}

.img-text {
  background: white;
}
```

This should help you continue your coding toward what you want to achieve

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

////////////* CSS reset end *////////////////
body {
  background: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p,
a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2%;
}

#gallery {
  background: #dfdfdf;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 125px 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h2 {
  color: #282828;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 45px;
}

h3 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.projects {
  background: #fff;
}

section:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.gallery-image {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 289px;
}

.img-text {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="gallery">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2>Our Gallery</h2>
      <h3>Lorem bizzle dolizzle sizzle amet</h3>

      <div class="projects">
        <div class="gallery-image">
          <div class="img-text">
            <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
            <h4>A project</h4>
            <p>Some text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="projects">
        <div class="gallery-image">
          <div class="img-text">
            <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
            <h4>A project</h4>
            <p>Some text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="projects">
        <div class="gallery-image">
          <div class="img-text">
            <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
            <h4>A project</h4>
            <p>Some text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just wanted to ask, why `.gallery-image a` needs `display:block` ?

Comment: @KestVir you can remove it, not needed here

Comment: @KestVir a `block` element will take the whole row. By default `<div>` is a block element for example.

Comment: Ok, now that is clear, thanks. I also have another question. https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/BReraN on line 34, I tried to add a `<p>` and give it a margin top, so that the content in the `<p class="margin-top">`  is further away from the gallery content  , but it gives that margin on top of the images. How should I solve this ? Maybe it's a clearfix problem if I'm not mistaken, but the clearfix didin't help.

Comment: @KestVir hm, I tried, can't really tell (https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/LyKmgN), try to make a post, I'm sure someone could help you with that! good luck

Comment: Sorry for writing after some time has passed, but I can't figure this one out. If I were to remove the `background: white` in `.gallery-image a` , then a tiny space between the `img-text` and the image of the bird becomes visible. This tiny space is about 2-3 px in height and comes from the '<a>` element. Now your fix of coloring it white works, but why does it (the tiny space between the elements) come up in the first place ? I've looked into similar code of different plates, but couldn't find this issue occurring anywhere else.

Comment: @KestVir, to be honest, I'm not sure why. try to make another post about the reason behind it? I updated my code to wrap the <a> and text together so you don't need to define two background color, but still seems the <a> leave a small space at the end too